# Auto-fix missing Python f-string prefix in insert mode

Tags: vimscript, filetype-python

I am constantly forgetting to add the `f` prefix in Python when I'm within a string and start inserting a variable (`"foo bar {var}"`).

I then do: `<ESC>F"if<ESC>f{a` and finish the f-string.

I'm wondering if there is a way (or an existing plugin) to trigger those Vim actions in insert mode when editing a `.py` file and typing `{` within a quoted string (`"foo bar {`) if the preceding quote is not prefixed by `f`.

It's a nit, and I'm lazy, I know. However, it happens approximately 100% of the time and it's annoying.

Wondering how I could auto-fix this on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pointed to this Neovim plugin by a fellow Vimer on a Discord I frequent. It meets my needs perfectly. For non-Neovim users, it should be possible to adapt Vivian's answer to achieve the same behavior.

https://github.com/roobert/f-string-toggle.nvim

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

```
inoremap <expr> { (map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")') == ['pythonString'] && search('f"', 'bn', line('.')) == 0) ? "<Esc>m'F\"if<Esc>`'la{" : '{'
```

The expression: `map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")') == ['pythonString']` detect if you are inserting text into a Python string.

The expression `search('f"', 'bn', line('.')) == 0)` detect if the string starts with `f"`

If both are true the following string is input `` <Esc>m'F"if<Esc>`'la{ ``

- `<Esc>` switch to normal mode
- `m'` mark the current position if mark `'`
- `F"` search the start of the string
- `if<Esc>` insert the `f` and switch back to normal mode
- `` `'l `` switch back to the edition position (the `l` seems necessary because of the insertion of the `f`)
- `a{` insert the `{`

Answer (score 1):

For those preferring a one-liner to installing a plugin, you could use a substitution with a conditional expression (see `:help :s` and `:help :s\=`).   Plugin f-string-toggle.nvim suggests mapping `<Leader>f` so why not also use it:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>f <Cmd>substitute/f\?\ze["']/\=submatch(0) == 'f' ? '' : 'f'<CR>
```

It finds 0 or 1 'f's, followed by single or double quotes. If found, the 'f' will be replaced with an empty string. If not found, an 'f' will be inserted. This means `<Leader>f` will toggle f-strings and work with all flavors of Python's strings:

```python
'single'
"double"
'''three singles'''
"""three doubles"""
```

Substitution is a line-wise operation, it does have some shortcomings:

```python
print("oops, it only modifies the", "{first} string in the line")
'''Works on the first line of a multi-line string,
but not on the following lines,
and will go terribly wrong on the last line -> f'''
```

For a one-liner, I'd say it doesn't perform too bad compared to 71 lines of Lua.